# Нахождение размеров экрана

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как узнать размеры экрана с помощью *PyQt* и *Python3*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот несколько вариантов:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Показать размер экрана", self, clicked=self.resizeWindow))
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def resizeWindow(self):

        self.label.setText(
        "Получить ширину и высоту экрана: \n\n"
        "QApplication.desktop() - `{}`, `{}`\n"
            "".format( QApplication.desktop().width(),  
                       QApplication.desktop().height()) +
        "QApplication.instance().desktop() - `{}`, `{}`\n"
            "".format( QApplication.instance().desktop().width(),  
                       QApplication.instance().desktop().height()) +
        "QApplication.instance().desktop().availableGeometry() - `{}`, `{}`\n"
            "".format( QApplication.instance().desktop().availableGeometry().width(),  
                       QApplication.instance().desktop().availableGeometry().height()) + 
        "app.desktop().screenGeometry() - `{}`, `{}`\n"
            "".format( app.desktop().screenGeometry().width(),  
                       app.desktop().screenGeometry().height()) +    
        "app.desktop().availableGeometry() - `{}`, `{}`\n"
            "".format( app.desktop().availableGeometry().width(),  
                       app.desktop().availableGeometry().height()) +                         
        "QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()) - `{}`, `{}`\n"
            "".format( QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().width(),  
                       QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().height()) +
        "QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()) - `{}`, `{}`\n"
            "".format( QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().width(),  
                       QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().height())                        
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt

def get_size_of_desktop():
    desktop = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv).desktop()
    return (desktop.width(), desktop.height()) 

print(get_size_of_desktop())
```